How can I block these Edge and Chrome settings?
https://imgur.com/a/fVPo4DV
It says: "Your Privacy is important for Microsoft Edge... bla bla bla... " I can either click on Accept or Deny All. This always pops up when Edge is opened for the first time.
https://imgur.com/a/T5e4Vb5
This seems to be the Chrome first run wizard altho I'm not sure.
I want to disable both as part of the image either thru a script or a registry tweak or a GPO.

Is this in a business environment? Are you trying to fix this for a single computer, or organization wide?

@music2myear This is a homelab, workgroup environment. Many computers, about 30 or so.
